# The meaning of an awk command

Tags: awk, gawk

I am trying to understand `gawk` in shell scripting. The command below is trying to count the number of paragraphs based on two (or more) consecutive new lines marking the end of a paragraph.

```
gawk 'END{print "Number of paragraphs: "NR}' RS="" tmp.txt
```

How does it work?

Comment: You might start with an actual problem statement and what you're trying to do...

Comment: @Ryan J it should count number of paragraph?

Comment: based on two consecutive new line

Comment: why bash, shell and unix tag if the question is about gawk?

Comment: i am new in stackoverflow

Comment: @ShinTakezou i edit it since the gawk used in shell scripting??

Comment: @john you're running it from the shell, but the question seems mainly about g-awk — it would be the same running it from windows "cmd", if there's a porting of gawk on windows: it's just a mean to execute the command, but I wouldn't focus on "scripting", being just "execute this command".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GNU [`awk`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Records) manual says of RS:

> The empty string `""` (a string without any characters) has a special meaning as the value
>   of RS. It means that records are separated by one or more blank lines and nothing else.

So, your program can be parsed as follows:

```
gawk 'END{print "Number of paragraphs: "NR}' RS="" tmp.txt
```

1. Run the `gawk` command.
2. The `gawk` script is `END{print "Number of paragraphs: "NR}` (the single quotes are removed by the shell).  When the input is ended, it prints the value of NR preceded by a phrase.  NR is the number of records read. Note that this is using the implicit concatenation operator between the phrase and NR. It could also be written `print "Number of paragraphs:", NR` and it would produce the same result.
3. `RS=""` is actually seen by `gawk` as `RS=` (the double quotes are removed by the shell).  This sets the special mode referenced from the manual.  Here, two or more consecutive newlines will be counted as the end of a paragraph, as will EOF.
4. The file processed is `tmp.txt`.

So, the command works because of a special case built into `gawk`.

Everything in this discussion also applies to standard `awk`.

Comment: but `"string" "something"` and `"string", "something"` are different: one is "pure" concatenation, the latter put the field separator between the pieces. (just checked by testing)

Comment: Yes, they are different. You might notice that there isn't a space after the colon in the alternative I proposed — that's inserted as an OFS (output field separator) character between the two arguments (the 'phrase' and NR) because of the comma separating the arguments.  The print statement in the question has a single argument; the revision has two.

Comment: so RS="" menas whats?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler got it, didn't notice the missing space inside the string — though the meaning is different, thus I would prefer the "space" version

Comment: @john: What does the quote from the manual say?  _The empty string "" (a string without any characters) has a special meaning as the value of RS. It means that records are separated by one or more blank lines and nothing else._  The `RS=""` on the command line sets the variable RS inside `awk`.  You can set any variable, built-in or of your own making, on the command line using `var=value` notation; you can optionally prefix such arguments with `-v`, so `awk -v RS= 'END{…}' tmp.txt` would also do the same job.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  and this gawk -F'[.?;!]' 'END {print "Number of sentences: "NF-1}' RS='^$' tmp.txt?

Comment: When you run `gawk -F'[.?;!]' 'END{…}'` sets the field separator to any of 4 characters — `.`, `?`, `;`, `!` (where most of those are expected, but `;` is not normally regarded as marking the end of a sentence).  This gives a crude way of counting the number of sentences on the last line of the file, or thereabouts. (I need to think about the `RS='^$'` bit — but you should too.)  However, you really should look at the manual to find these things out.  I've given you a URL to the manual — you should use it.  Read and learn!

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler can u explain more??

Comment: @john: No, I can't. Or, more to the point: No, I am not willing to do so.  You need to read the manual and experiment. What happens without the RS part; what happens without the square brackets; what happens …